# Exec fails when applied to a code with a new type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file `multiply.py` with the following contents:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Result(NamedTuple):
    product: int
    desc: str

def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> Result:
    return Result(
        product=a * b,
        desc=f"muliplied {a} and {b}",
    )

x=4
y=5
print(multiply(x, y))
```

If I run it just like that it of course yields the expected result:

```bash
$ python multiply.py 
Result(product=20, desc='muliplied 4 and 5')
```

However I'm trying to run it with `exec` function from `main.py`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

gl, lo = {}, {}
exec(Path("multiply.py").read_text(), gl, lo)
```

and this time the output is disappointing:

```bash
$ python main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    exec(Path("multiply.py").read_text(), gl, lo)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in multiply
NameError: name 'Result' is not defined
```

Why is that? Can't I create new types in the code executed by `exec`?

Comment: `Result` is placed in the local environment (you can print `gl` and `lo` to see that).  If you pass a single dict (`exec(..., gl, gl))`) it will work.  `exec` is a somewhat strange beast, which is why most recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are passing two different dictionaries for locals and globals, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If `exec` gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will
> be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition

Class bodies are not an enclosing scope, functions defined in the class body do not have access to variables defined in the class body. This is the reason that in a method definition you must use `self.` to refer to another method.

To elaborate a little on what I mean about `self`, here's an example of actually just running the code you have in a class body, and seeing how it behaves:

```
In [1]: class NS:
   ...:     from typing import NamedTuple
   ...:
   ...:     class Result(NamedTuple):
   ...:         product: int
   ...:         desc: str
   ...:
   ...:     def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> Result:
   ...:         return Result(
   ...:             product=a * b,
   ...:             desc=f"muliplied {a} and {b}",
   ...:         )
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: NS.multiply(1, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 1
----> 1 NS.multiply(1, 2)

Cell In [1], line 9, in NS.multiply(a, b)
      8 def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> Result:
----> 9     return Result(
     10         product=a * b,
     11         desc=f"muliplied {a} and {b}",
     12     )

NameError: name 'Result' is not defined
```

In any case, `exec` is a function that is typically misused. There are times when it is perfectly fine, but *often* it is the case that when people reach for `exec`/`eval` there is a better way to do it in Python.